# apache2 stops when I logout from SSH

Tags: ssh, apache-2.4, debian-jessie

I am running Debian 8 Jessie and I have Apache 2.4.25-3+deb9u3 running under my login userid.  When I login via SSH to the server and then log out, apache terminates.  This also happens on Debian 9 Stretch.   It didn't work this way when I was running on Debian 7 Wheezy (I think it was apache 2.2).  I could log in and out all the time and Apache would still be running.

I looked at logind.conf and KillUserProcesses is set to no.

I would like apache2 to never stop running unless I manually stop it.  Any ideas?

Comment: "running under my login userid" how? did you background or `disown` it?

Comment: I don't understand your question.    In /etc/apache2/envars  I set APACHE_RUN_USER to my userid, and APACHE_RUN_GROUP to the group my ID is in.

Comment: what command did you use to start apache?

Comment: It autostarts at boot.  I think the /etc/init.d/apache2 script starts it.

Comment: hmm, there should be no relation between your SSH session and the init-system started apache, especially if they are different user accounts

Comment: They are not different user accounts.   ps -ef | grep apache   shows the processes are using my userid.

Comment: Found the solution.   I needed to edit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and provide this value:

Mutex posixsem

Answer (score 1):

Ideally Apache should run under its own user, like www-data. Is there a reason why you are running it as yourself?

Anyway, if you absolutely need to run it from your own user you should start it with `nohup` at the end on the command . This way when you logout the system won't send a hup (hang up) signal to that process when you logout.

From the man pages:

```
nohup(1) - Linux man page

Name

nohup - run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty
Synopsis

nohup COMMAND [ARG]...
nohup OPTION
Description

Run COMMAND, ignoring hangup signals.

--help
display this help and exit
--version
output version information and exit
If standard input is a terminal, redirect it from /dev/null. If standard output is a terminal, append output to 'nohup.out' if possible, '$HOME/nohup.out' otherwise. If standard error is a terminal, redirect it to standard output. To save output to FILE, use 'nohup COMMAND > FILE'.

NOTE: your shell may have its own version of nohup, which usually supersedes the version described here. Please refer to your shell's documentation for details about the options it supports.
```

Comment: How do you nohup when apache is a service.  It is restarted like this:  sudo service apache2 restart .       I set it up with my own user id so I didn't have any file permissions issues between apache and my user.  I guess I could use groups to solve the permissions issue.